# Dojo 2 How to achieve two-way binding for input?

Tags: dojo2

How to achieve 2 way data binding for input in dojo 2?

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ textValue: e.target.value });}
<Input name='title' defaultValue={this.state.textValue} placeholder='title...' onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I know this is how we do in React but don't know how to achieve in dojo 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to achieve 2 way data binding in Dojo 2.

InputWidget:-

```
interface IInputProps {
   value: string;
   onChange(event: Event): void;
}
export class InputWidget extends WidgetBase<IInputProps> {
  private _onChange (event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.properties.onChange && this.properties.onChange((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  }

  protected render(): DNode {
    const { value } = this.properties;
    return v('input', { 
        key: "input",
        type: "text",
        value
        onchange: this._onChange
    });
  }
}
```

InputWrapper widget:-

```
export class InputWrapper extends WidgetBase<IWrapperProps> {
  private inputValue: string = ''; 
  protected inputValueChanges(value: string) {
    this.inputValue = value;
    this.invalidate();
  }

  protected render(): DNode {
    <div>
        {w(InputWidget, {onchange: this.inputValueChanges, value: this.inputValue })}
        <span>Input Value:- {this.inputValue}</span>
    </div>

  }
}
```

This is the solution to achieve 2 way data binding in Dojo 2.

Hope this will be helpful! :(

Answer (score 2):

In fact React supports only one-way binding, and your example illustrates it well. You need to update state, to re-render react component. 
And as far as I understood from dojo2 docs and tutorials, there is almost same approach under the hood. Take a look [here](https://dojo.io/docs/fundamentals/reactive_programming/index.html)

> Dojo 2 is built around unidirectional, top-down property propagation where it is the parent widget’s job to pass properties down to its children. In fact, a child widget has no direct reference to a parent widget! When a property changes, widgets are re-rendered (using an efficient virtual DOM) to reflect the updated state.

And it may look like this:

```
private _addWorker() {
        this._workerData = this._workerData.concat(this._newWorker);
        this._newWorker = {};
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

You change data and call invalidate() to re-render widget.